# Apartment in Berlin for long stay (Two months)

Tags: online-resources, accommodation, berlin

I am looking for a good apartment in Berlin for a family of two, can anyone provide site where I can find such options(I would prefer direct contacts rather than some booking sites).

Comment: What is long? A month? A year? Two years?

Comment: There is already a question covering this topic : http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14448/where-can-i-find-short-term-apartment-rental-offers-in-berlin (well it still depends on what you mean by 'long')

Comment: Sry missed it by mistake, updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A popular site for finding apartments in Germany is [ImmobilienScout24](http://www.immobilienscout24.de/). A competitor is [Immowelt](http://www.immowelt.de/). Note that, normally, apartments are rented unfurnished.

If you are looking for furnished apartments for up to just some months, have a look at sites such as [wg-gesucht.de](http://www.wg-gesucht.de) or [zwischenmiete.de](http://www.zwischenmiete.de). I wrote about that in an [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14448/where-can-i-find-short-term-apartment-rental-offers-in-berlin) to a question about short term rent.

Comment: Hi! I suggest you update your good answer in this other question, I think we should close this duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14448/where-can-i-find-short-term-apartment-rental-offers-in-berlin/14450#14450

Answer (score 0):

[AirBnB](https://www.airbnb.co.nz/s/Berlin--Germany) has quite a large selection for Berlin.