# Renting an apartment for 2-3 months in Italy

Tags: online-resources, italy, accommodation, rental

I've used the [Habitaclia](http://www.habitaclia.com) for renting apartments in Spain short/medium term (2-3 months). I am looking to do the same in Italy. I've tried [Airbnb](http://www.airbnb.com) but it seems to be geared for even shorter durations (1-4 weeks).

Is there a website for Italian rentals akin to Spain's [Habitaclia](http://www.habitaclia.com) or those listed in the similar question for Berlin: [Where can I find short term apartment rental offers in Berlin?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14448/where-can-i-find-short-term-apartment-rental-offers-in-berlin?lq=1)

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Please review the FAQ for the site and adjust your question because list questions like this are considered non-constructive

Comment: @Karlson thanks! i don't know how to improve my question though

Comment: I just edited your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Kijiji](http://www.kijiji.it/) and [Bakeca.it](http://www.bakeca.it/home.php) are two popular sites for classified ads, you'll need to know Italian though :)

Comment: You can always use Google Translate :)

Comment: Google Translate usually gives an idea, but I have seen it convert negative to positive and vice versa.  Never depend on it for anything important.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use yet Google Translator to speak over the phone to the landperson :-)

Answer (score 0):

While AirBNB may not be as good as a site like that suggested, it does allow filtering the search in many ways.  With the criteria shown here, 53 places in the entire country appeared.  [image] Narrow done the location and increase the price and see what happens.